What writing system are they using in "Isekai Cheat Magician"?
What language or writing system are the characters using in the anime "Isekai Cheat Magician"?
For example:


Is it just a made-up language and writing system or is it based off of any existing language and writing system?

AFAIK probably made up. European languages basically are Egyptian hieroglyphs -> Phoenician -> Greek -> Latin/Cyrillic. Many middle eastern languages go Phoenician -> Aramaic. Hieroglyphs are basically pictures, Phoenician is hard lines (to chisel into stone) and modern languages are curvy. The characters in the book have half and full widths (similar to CJK). Where the ones in the map have proportional widths (or at the least kerning). I've looked for similar characters but can't find any sets in Unicode. I think the author made the 'ancient' alphabet using Japanese character rules.

It's English, just a weird font.


Do you know what font it is?

@Henkyo I do not, but it's likely a custom font. Youjo Senki used this method, too. If you are just interested in a cool looking cryptic font I recommend the Youjo Senki font, which someone decoded and made available for download as a font file.

Out of curiosity, where did you find this piece of information? Or did you come up with the decryption on your own?

@Gae.S. I decrypted the Cheat Magician font myself by looking at the map. (Btw, there's actually a typo in the top right, where they wrote "empaire" instead of empire.) I started with the word "Savanna" since it was easiest to guess having one letter appear three times and another one appearing two times. Not that I was sure it would be that word. I just pretended it was correct and looked where that would take me with all the other words.

You can give it a try yourself, as I forgot the part that is under the subtitles. It says "?ig? Mountain" with both question marks being the same letter. Solution: (stop reading if you want to come up with it yourself now.) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur High Mountain.
